# Error: Call to undefined function views_include() in include_once() (line 9 of code_dir:- \sites\all\modules\views\includes\plugins.inc)

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-7

Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Error messageError: Call to undefined function views_include() in include_once() (line 9 of code_dir:-\sites\all\modules\views\includes\plugins.inc).

If I commented this line, Then it is working fine. what is meaning of this line **"views_include('base');"**

Comment: We could better help you if you can provide full class code of include_once()? Also you can apply suggestion form "how to ask a good question" here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask